# How to track custom parameter with Google Analytics and utm.gif

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

**The situation**
I'd like to use GA to track some serverside operations. That's why I cant make use of the GA JavaScript functions. But, as you might know, you can request the utm.gif right from your server. This already works fine.

**The Problem**
I'd like to trackt custom parameters. But I have no idea how to add them in the right format to the url-request

This one should do the custom parms. But I didn't get any results in GA.

```
utme=5(Init*load_success*http://www.mydomain.de)8(userstatus)9(fan)11(2)
```

**Full list of params:**

```
    ref   ts
    utmac   UA-XXXXXX-5
    utmcc   __utma=186215409.1789216404.1265552708.1280074861.1280493144.21;+__utmz=;
    utmcs   ISO-8859-1
    utmdt   Button
    utme    5(Init*load_success*http://www.mydomain.de)8(mycustomvar)9(mycustomvalue)11(2)
    utmfl   -
    utmhn   mydomain.de
    utmje   -
    utmn    1114675642
    utmp    button
    utmr    http://www.mydomain.de
    utmsc   -
    utmsr   -
    utmul   de-de
    utmwv   4.5.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what's going wrong, given what you posted, but how about you write out what you want to send the traditional way (with javascript) and put it on a test page.  Use firebug or whatever to grab the requested url that's built and compare it to what you have now.

Comment: p.s. - dunno if you knew or not but GA has a 24hr delay on data showing up.

Comment: Also you may need to set your host (fake a browser's host info), GA may be receiving it just fine but weeding it out.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, it would be nice to know what the final value of the param(s) were that you needed to pass. I guess I will have to do the same thing, which is tedious because I've only been working with the server-to-server version thus far

Answer (score 1):

The value of the utme gif Request parameter is **encoded** by ga.js--it's the only one that is, as far as i know.

Calling *__trackEvent* is the usual way to set the value of utme. These are client-side events though, which is no doubt why you are trying to set utme directly.

So if you just want to bind *5(Init*load_success*http://www.mydomain.de)8(userstatus)9(fan)11(2)* to the variable utme, and you can't rely on user-behavior to trigger that binding, then here's what i suggest:

Pack your data into a **'custom variable' scoped to the page**--this way, when the __trackPageview() is called, the value will be set.

Here's the analytics code required in your HTML to implement that:

The method signature for a custom variable:

```
pageTracker._setCustomVar(slot,    // integer between 1 and 5, inclusive (just use '1')
                          name,    // user-defined name for the custom variable
                          value,   // string representing the value for the custom variable
                          scope,   // you want '3' for page-level (an int, not a string though)  
);
```

Within the HTML (order matter, of course):

```
pageTracker.__setCustomvar(1, "A Name", "A Value", 3);
pageTracker.__trackPageview();
```

A key point here is that the parameter 'value' can be set dynamically, so for the 'value' parameter, i guess you want to pass in *5(Init*load_success*http://www.mydomain.de)8(userstatus)9(fan)11(2)*

Finally, here are the two key sources ([Implementation Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html), [Usage Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#usage)) on Custom Variables from the GA Team

Comment: He wants to use it to track server-side operations, not client-side operation.  Hence not using javascript.

Comment: Well, javascript is used to capture/record server-side data all the time (e.g., count 404s served). The constraint in the OP's Q--as they have described it--is that they want to measure something *not* triggered by user interaction (e.g., you can't use event tracking, which is what i think he might have tried). The solution i offered captures the information using js and that capture is triggered on page loading.